# JMeter - No root certificate found in bin directory

Tags: jmeter, root-certificate

I am trying to record a Script using Jmeter recorder. For this I tried to import root certificate from the bin folder in Firefox. But I can't see a certificate there. I also tried to download sample JMeter certificate from GitHub and installed it. But Firefox rejected it saying that I do not have the corresponding private key.

Could anyone please tell why is my certificate missing? Also it would be helpful if someone could tell me how to generate the certificate in Jmeter.

My Java version is "1.8.0_251"
JMeter version - 5.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The certificate is being generated under "bin" folder of your JMeter installation when you start [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder), to wit when you click "Start" button:

[image]

Before that you will not see any certificate.

The certificate file is `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` and it will appear assuming your properly installed Java and this guy can be installed into Firefox browser ("Authorities" tab of the Firefox Certificate Manager)

Don't download any certificates from Internet and if you did - don't install them as you're putting yourself under the risk of [MITM attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack), use **only the certificate your very own JMeter generated**

Also be aware that there is an alternative (easier?) way of recording a JMeter test: [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium/), in this case you won't have to worry about proxies and SSL certificates.

Comment: Thanks for bringing out the security concern. I will uninstall the downloaded certificate. And I have successfully generated the authentic J Meter certificate.

Answer (score 0):

1. First you need to Delete Proxyserver.jks file under bin folder. Then
   go to jmeter Set Target controller as the HTTP(S) Test Script
   Recorder.

   Start the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder.

   Referesh the bin folder. The Apachejmetercertificate is being
   generated under "bin" folder of your JMeter installation when you
   start HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder[image]